# Installing a bootloader on an ARM Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, arm, bootloader

I have purchased [this LPC1788FBD144,551 MCU](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?sku=82T9494) and  [this LPC1313FBD48/01,15 MCU](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?sku=83T7141) and I want to install a bootloader in assembly on them which can call a function in C. How can I install the bootloader on the ARM MCU? Would I install it directly on the MCU or on a separate component (if so can you show me which part on the newark website)?

Comment: Have you verified that there is not already one there from the factory? Bootloader for what external interface?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I want to create a custom bootloader for the device.

Comment: So you say, but first you are going to have to decide what you want your bootloader to do, and research the capabilities of the target chips - what they already do, if they support partial locking of pages, if they have enough ram to run the bootloaded application there rather than flashing it (if you prefer), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Both devices have on-chip bootloaders that will always be executed. With the LPC17xx, you can write a secondary bootloader to execute custom code that will run directly after. You simply need to direct your IDE to place the code at location 0x00.

On the [documentation page](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m3/LPC1788FET208.html#documentation), have a look at AN11257 and AN11258. These discuss creating secondary bootloaders (SBL) to load code from SPI or I2C respectively. This could retrieve code from a PC or an external memory device.

From AN11257:

> In these MCUs, the primary  boot loader resides in the boot block. The
>   boot loader is executed every time the part is  powered on or reset.
>   It can execute the ISP command handler or the user application  code,
>   which is stored in sector 0 of internal flash memory.
>
> The SBL in
>   this project refers to a user-defined application that provides the
>   user with an  option to update the User Application Firmware or
>   execute the previously programmed  User Application Firmware. It is
>   placed from the address 0x00 so that when the primary  boot loader
>   runs user application, it executes first.

I couldn't find similar documentation on the LPC13xx. But it's primary bootloader has a bit more functionality built-in. Specifically the ability to load new programs via UART. Your version lacks the USB functionality they talk about in the [User Guide](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10375.pdf):

> The bootloader code is executed every time the part is powered on or
>   reset (see  Figure 63). The loader can either execute the ISP command
>   handler or the user  application code, or it can obtain the boot image
>   as an attached MSC device through  USB. A LOW level during reset at
>   the PIO0_1 pin is considered an external hardware  request to start
>   the ISP command handler or the USB device enumeration without 
>   checking for a valid user code first. The state of PIO0_3 determines
>   whether the UART or  USB interface will be used:
>
> • If PIO0_3 is sampled HIGH, the bootloader connects the LPC134x as a
>   MSC USB  device to a PC host. The LPC134x flash memory space is
>   represented as a drive in  the host’s Windows operating system.
>
> • If PIO0_3 is sampled LOW, the bootloader configures the UART serial
>   port and calls  the ISP command handler.
>
> Remark: On the LPC131x parts (no USB), the state of pin PIO0_3 does
>   not matter.

You can still make the first instructions executed after the primary bootloader act as a custom secondary bootloader. You just need to locate that code at the proper address. How this is done is heavily dependent on your IDE. Refer to your IDE's documentation on how to properly control code placement into the desired sectors.

Comment: If I do this from my mac how could I set my IDE so that it sets the address to 0x00? Specifically with nasm or gcc?

Comment: @Coder404 You'll have to create a linker file for gcc that places the object file of your bootloader code at a specific section located at a specific address. Take a look at the second to last example [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_19.html) where they place the `all` object file into the `outputa` section at address `0x10000`. I would also suggest telling gcc to print a [map file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391458/map-file-with-gcc-on-osx) to make sure you got it right.

Comment: What kind of a physical connection would I use to install the code onto the MCU?

Comment: @Coder404 The short answer is: serial bus. But each chip is slightly different. See Chapter 32 of the [LPC17xx User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10360.pdf) and Chapter 21 of the [LPC13xx User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10375.pdf) for the details.

Comment: You would not install the bootloader since it is already there from the factory.  To communicate with the bootloader you would need to use an interface it supports - you'll need to see the documentation for the specific chip, but commonly some subset of logic-level serial, SPI, or USB is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I would say everything you need is already provided by NXP.

It is the same principle for all LPC1700 microcontrollers, so either use the Flashmagic tool, or call IAP (In Application Programming) functions to provide your own custom bootloader. You usually have to do so if you need the boot loadwer running over Ethernet or USB, and not via the RS232. Still, it does make sense to call IAP functions for Flash programming, and not to do it yourself.

Check [this thread](http://knowledgebase.nxp.trimm.net/showthread.php?t=2882), answers provided by Zero and Rob68 are always high quality straight to the problem.

Download the [Flashmagic tool](http://www.flashmagictool.com/), and study it's users manual (provided in PDF). Your devices are supprted.

Check also [this link](http://www.keil.com/forum/18723/) where some more specific problems were discussed.